# Can DL store ASCII codes for computer keys?

Tags: assembly, ascii, keypress, cpu-registers, emu8086

I looked at another question where someone compared the DL register to ASCII value 43 in order to receive a result whenever the + key was pressed, does this mean that DL register can store ASCII values based on what key was pressed?

I haven't tried it myself yet because I'm not very familiar with assembly, but I wonder if this is true.

Comment: The bios will store the key code in `AL` automatically, but yes, you can `MOV DL,AL` after the fact and compare to `DL` later. It won't be put into `DL` automatically, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The DL register can indeed store ASCII codes in the range 0 to 255.

> does this mean that DL register can store ASCII values based on what key was pressed?

**The value has to be put there by your assembly program**.

Using BIOS:

```
mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
int  16h       ; -> AL is ASCII, AH is scancode
mov  dl, al    ; Move to DL if the program so desires
cmp  dl, 43    ; Compare for '+'
```

or using DOS

```
mov  ah, 01h   ; DOS.GetCharacter
int  16h       ; -> AL is ASCII
mov  dl, al    ; Move to DL if the program so desires
cmp  dl, '+'
```